# Eager fetching the entire object tree in grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

So I have an few objects in the domain which are in a hasMany relation with each other as below

```
Class Car {
    String name
    SortedSet tires = [] as SortedSet
    static hasMany = [tires: Tire]
}

Class Tire {
    String type
    SortedSet screws = [] as SortedSet
    static hasMany = [screws: Screw]
}

Class Screws {
     String type
}
```

Now I would like to take the entire object tree offline for a certain kind of car that I can get by a findByName. I know we can do a fetch eager on the finder, but that goes down just one level. As in the example I have 2 levels or more.

So my question is this. Is there an elegant solution to eager fetch the entire object tree and then use it around without grails/Hibernate firing off another query to fetch the details.

I tried the following which seem to have a similar result but are hardly elegant.

The withCriteria solution

```
def cars = Car.withCriteria {
    tires {
        screws {
            join 'screws'
        }
    }
```

Also I tried converting the entire tree into JSON and reparsing it, but that seems to be an overkill. I guess basically I am trying to get the whole object tree offline. Any thoughts if this can be done easily or at all?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the mapping closure:

```
Class Car {
    String name
    SortedSet tires = [] as SortedSet
    static hasMany = [tires: Tire]
    static mapping = {
        tires lazy: false
    }
}

Class Tire {
    String type
    SortedSet screws = [] as SortedSet
    static hasMany = [screws: Screw]
    static mapping = {
        screws lazy: false
    }
}

Class Screws {
     String type
}
```

Maybe you should to take the exception like the rule, I mean, you can to configure your domains class to be `lazy: false` and to call your finder with fetch lazy:

```
def cars = Car.findAllByType(type: "Alfa", [fetch: [tires: 'lazy']])
```

I don't know if that is a valid option but you can try it.

Comment: This is definitely an option, except I wanted this to happen only on a special case and not the regular behavior for all my other calls. Which is why I was avoiding updating the domain.

Comment: I guess you can try with hql fetch but is hardly more elegant that your withCriteria solution. Remember, you can encapsulate your actual solution in a static method into domain class, create the unit tests and refinate it later.

Comment: I suppose. It would have been nice if in grails there was a way to literally take an object offline. I did also try cloning it, but it gets too complex as you descend into the tree.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer as probably the best way to make this work. Still looking for a way to get grails to do this thru finders. Will update post if I find another way for this.

Comment: This works. Now how would we get down to a lazy fetch of screws in the  same statement. Would it be like fetch: [tires.screws: 'lazy'] you think?